# Superfluous scroll bars in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, scrollbar

I have a WinForms application with a `ListView` which scales with the main program window. OnResize, I adjust the width of the columns to fit the full width of the `ListView`. Now when I switch from fullscreen to normal, I get a horizontal scrollbar. This scrollbar cannot be scrolled, i.e. the width it covers is 100% of the width of the ListView. In other words, I want to get rid of this scrollbar. If I shortly touch the window resize handlers, without actually resizing the window, the width is recomputed and the scrollbar disappears. How can I get rid of that scrollbar automatically?

```
column1.Width = fixedWidth;
column2.Width = listView.Width - fixedWidth - System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
```

Comment: Have you subtracted the width of the vertical scrollbar (if any) from the width of the listview to calculate the width of each column?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria yes, adding the code to the question

Comment: `column1` and `column2` are column *headers* though not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Ok i have found some old code, my solution was `column2.Width = listView.Width - fixedWidth - System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - 8;` (yes it's dumb but works :)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, the problem is not that I can't compute the width, the problem is that the right width still creates a useless scrollbar. (I know it's the right one because even the scollbar knows it's the right one, it disappears with an embarassed look on its face once I click it ;)

Comment: Strange i've a similar behavior, but my scrollbar doesn't disappear, if i apply the method exposed simply disappears (i'm using .NET 4.5, VS2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.  It starts with you using the listview's Width property.  Which isn't correct on a ListView with borders, you need to use the ClientSize.Width property.  The second problem is related to way automatic layout is calculated, it causes the Resize event to fire too soon.  You can work around that by delaying the adjustment with Control.BeginInvoke().  Like this:

```
    private void listView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            var lv = (ListView)sender;
            var w = 0;
            for (int ix = 0; ix < lv.Columns.Count - 1; ++ix) w += lv.Columns[ix].Width;
            w = Math.Max(0, lv.ClientSize.Width - w);
            lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].Width = w;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This not only works beautifully (I compute the widths differently, but wrapping the computation into BeginInvoke does the trick), but the notion of an event firing too early also fits very well to the observed behaviour. Not too mention using ClientSize is obviously better now that I'm aware of it ;) 

Out of curiosity, does the BeginInvoke have any other function than to delay execution, hoping that whatever still needs doing will be done?

Comment: Sure, just read the MSDN article for Control.BeginInvoke().  It doesn't actually mention this usage :)

Comment: nah I mean here (ok reading the article might not hurt either ;)

Answer (score 2):

To fill the remaining space with the last column's width you can do this, of course we have to do this whenever the form is resized:

```
//Resize event handler for your Form1
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e){
    column2.Width = -2;
}
//ColumnWidthChanged event handler
private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e){
    int lastIndex = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != lastIndex) listView1.Columns[lastIndex].Width = -2;
}
//ColumnWidthChanging event handler
private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e){
    int lastIndex = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != lastIndex) listView1.Columns[lastIndex].Width = -2;
}
```

**NOTE**: You said you had your `ListView` scaled `with the main program window`, I don't know what you did to achieve that, but I suggest you should use the `Anchor` property, set `listView1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;`.

Comment: King King answer is correct, I've faced the same issue sometimes in the past and its solution works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting thing to know, but it doesn't work. It sets the size to the maximum length of all elements instead of cutting them of. When there's enough space, it doesn't fully use it. But then I also need to apply it on the first, not the last column - ?

Concerning your note, it's done via 

    listView.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

while sitting in a SplitPanel with the same property

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem.  This magic -2 is just a hack to compensate for the borders of the ListView, easily fixed by using ClientSize.Width instead of Width.

Comment: @Nicolas78 It works for me, I think somehow **you changed the width of one of the columns**, if so we also have to update the `Width` of the last column. And the code is applied for the last column only, all the other columns should have fixed width, however with my updated code, you can resize their width at runtime so that all your columns fill your grid's width.

Comment: But I want the first column to fill the width. However computing the width is something I can do, the problem was somewhere else, see Hans' answer

Comment: @Nicolas78 your code doesn't show that you want the first column to fill the width, if so it should have been `column1.Width = listView1.ClientSize.Width`

Comment: Oh. True. Sorry that got lost during beautification of my actual code. Didn't think it was important at that time and by the time I got to answer your answer I already forgot it ;)

Comment: @HansPassant it's not really some hack to compensate any thing, I've done some search on this and `.Width = -2` in fact sends the `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` message with the `lParam = -2`, at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761163(v=vs.85).aspx , you can see `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER=-2` means that if it's the last column, the width will be the remaining space.

Comment: (don't get me wrong this is upvoted and super-useful and will save a lot of time going forward, it just seems there was still another issue at work)